# How can I add <Run Text="xx"/> to TextBox c#? Or how can I append dynamic string to static string in TextBox?

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox, windows-phone-8.1, textblock

In WPF, I know that for TextBlock when I want to append some "dynamic" string to a string I can do something like the following :

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text ="static string"/>
    <Run Text="{Binding dynamicstring}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

However, the same method doesn't work for TextBox, is there anyway to do the same thing with TextBox

Comment: You need to define that in `ControlTemplate` of `TextBox`

Comment: Check [This](http://www.wpftutorial.net/templates.html) for example

Comment: @litaoshen it seem to me you should be looking into [`RichTextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox(v=vs.100).aspx) instead of `TextBox`

Comment: @dkozl thx first, but currently I cannot find RichTextBox in the toolbox, maybe because I'm writing some universal app (this one is for WP 8.1)

Comment: we can arrange 2 elements appropriately with homogeneous background to mimic what you want. It's harder when you want something reversed (appending static string to dynamic string). In that case we need to track the caret and adjust the static string element accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Try using RichEditBox.

```
<RichEditBox>
    <Paragraph>
       <Run Text="Static Text" />
       <Run Text="{Binding Dynamic}" />
    </Paragraph>
</RichEditBox>
```

If you're using Windows Phone Silverlight

```
<RichTextBox>
    <Paragraph>
       <Run Text="Static Text" />
       <Run Text="{Binding Dynamic}" />
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBox>
```