# Partially read-only textbox in c#

Tags: c#, char, position, uwp

I've got a list of illegal positions and characters that can't move from those positions. How would I prevent those from being modified in the TextChanged event? Every solution I've come up with has been extremely hacky and unreliable, or has relied on the KeyDown event, which doesn't prevent the user from deleting the read-only text in other ways (select the text and delete it, or just press the backspace key).

I've thought of doing something like this:

```
//CharPos is a class with an int (CharPos.Position) and a char that 
//should be at that int's position (CharPos.Ch)
foreach (CharPos p in IllegalPositions)
{
    console.Text = console.Text.Remove(p.Position, 1);
    console.Text = console.Text.Insert(p.Position, p.Ch.ToString());
}
```

But it completely messes up and goes on an infinite loop. And even if I stopped it from doing that, it wouldn't work if you changed the character count of the text, by using the delete key for example. Maybe I could use regex somehow? (I dunno, I have no experience at all with regex).

Comment: What is IllegalPositions?  Provide examples.  Are the positions and characters supposed to stay in the textbox permanently and the user enters characters between them?  Provide more detail.  Provide the actual code you used and your actual input.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was clear enough. I don't have access to my main PC right now, so can't add any code for the moment though. IllegalPositions is a list of positions in the string (defined by CharPos, a class that contains an int representing the position and Ch which is the original character). They are supposed to stay permanently, and yes, the user should be able to write text before and after, but never overwrite or remove any char in those positions.

Comment: What is `console.Text`?  I only know of `Console.Write` or `Console.WriteLine` in C#.  Your foreach loop looks good to me.  It removes at a particular position then adds the character.  I don't see the problem.  I need more details.  Is the application MVC, WebForms?  Are you using an asp:TextBox with auto postback?

Comment: As said in the tags, it's a UWP App. And console is the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Can you combine multiple TextBoxes (for editable parts) with TextBlocks (for readonly parts)? You would just need to play with styling of the two to match

Comment: I tried doing this, but it adds an absolute ton of other issues... :/

Comment: What issues do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check the link below:

[Disabling or making it readonly a part of the values in a Text Box (.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910923/disabling-or-making-it-readonly-a-part-of-the-values-in-a-text-box-net)

```
rtBox.Select(0, (rtBox.Text = "I am fixed content").Length);
rtBox.SelectionProtected = true;
rtBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: RichTextBox doesn't exist in UWP :/

Comment: What about TextBox? Previous solution: [append-dynamic-string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32977054/how-can-i-add-run-text-xx-to-textbox-c-or-how-can-i-append-dynamic-string)

Comment: That post didn't actually give a solution that worked without using RichEditBox, which doesn't have SelectionProtected in uwp :/